# Unable to delete .iso file, even with iobit unlocker

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am unable to delete a .iso file, stored under my download folder. 'file used by another program' pops up whenever I try to delete it.

I have used iobit unlocker and found that the file is being used by System.
Tried using iobit to delete it but still failed. need help.

Comment: Try rebooting your computer, then try to delete the file.

Comment: Is it mounted in PowerISO, Alcohol 120%, etc?

Comment: What troubleshooting has been tried to resolve? A as Doktoro indicated a reboot should resolve the conflict

Comment: Have you made sure it's not mounted to your virtual drives?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the file in command prompt? You can force delete the file from there:

del /f C:\users\user\file.iso

OR go to downloads by changing the directory:

C:\Users\User1> cd Downloads
C:\Users\User1\Downloads> del /f file.iso

Try to make sure the ISO is not mounted or used in a dvd/cd writing application.

Answer (score 0):

A simple restart should suffice, but if not, check which program is set to open `.iso` files on your computer (if you don't already know). You can right-click on the `.iso` file in question and check its properties to find out that information.

Next, you should check if there are any instances of that program running under the `Processes` tab in the `Task Manager`. If there are any such instances, simply end them and try to delete the file.

It could also be that a program is running at Startup and the `.iso` file you want to delete is still active within that application.